# how to show event in colorbox when clicked from calendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, calendar

This is the code that renders the fullcalendar:

```
<br><br>
<%= link_to 'View Events', events_path, class: 'btn btn-md btn-default' %>   | <%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path, class: 'btn btn-md btn-success',  data: {colorbox: true}, colorbox_iframe: true %>
<br><br>
<div id="calendar" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>
```

I modified `index.json.jbuilder` file:

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

This is the `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
// require turbolinks
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require colorbox-rails
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: '/events.json'
    });
});
```

My events are showing nicely on the calendar, but how do I make them appear in a colorbox when clicked from the calendar. I have correctly applied colorbox for other pages, but how do i do the same from the calendar?

Anyone please?

Comment: Fullcalendar provide events helper to handle click in the calendar. Check this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Comment: tried eventClick.colorbox() but didnt work....pls any idea somebody?